# Efficient Way to Select if a database row value match a group of string

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Efficient Way to Select if a database row value match a group of string

```
  SELECT id FROM tablename where 
    LeadStatus like "%Contact Attempt 1%" or 
    LeadStatus like "%Contact Attempt 2%" or 
    LeadStatus like "%Contact Attempt 3%" or 
    LeadStatus like "%Contact Attempt 4%" or 
    LeadStatus like "%Contact Attempt 5%" or 
    LeadStatus like "%Contact Attempt 6%" or 
    LeadStatus like "%Contact Attempt 7%" or 
    LeadStatus like "%Call Back/Follow-up%" or 
    LeadStatus like "%Working%" or 
    LeadStatus like "%Credit Pulled%" or 
    LeadStatus like "%Selected other Lender%" or 
    LeadStatus like "%Pre-Approved%" or 
    LeadStatus like "%Application Taken/Sent%" or 
    LeadStatus like "%Application Received%" or 
    LeadStatus like "%Submitted%" or 
    LeadStatus like "%Funded%" or 
    LeadStatus like "%Future Opportunity%" or 
    LeadStatus like "%Manager Review%"
```

I think it clear enough that what I want?

**Note :** I can't change the `LeadStatus` value as it is fetched from a API not in my control

Comment: If possible add a new table `Leadstatuses` with values `contact attempt`, ... Then make this column `leadstatus` a foreign key to this table.

Comment: No cant do that... as these are the value entered by the third party and can change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using the [IN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp) operator?

Here's an example at [SQLFiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/375f5/4).

You can build out the CSV list of strings dynamically & just insert it in between the parenthesis. The only drawback to using the IN operator though is that you cannot apply wild card searches (with the "%").

Comment: How to use the `IN` predicate with `LIKE` operators? like what he wrote in his question. The values in LeadStatus needs to be matched with `LIKE` operator not with `=`.

Comment: No. The values in `LeadStatus` needs to be matched with `LIKE` operator not with `=`

Comment: If you must use the LIKE operator, then there's no more concise way of writing your query.